# jupyter notebook connecting to Apache Spark 3.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, cluster-computing

I'm trying to connect my `Scala` kernel in a notebook environment to an existing `Apache 3.0 Spark cluster`.
I've tried the following methods in integrating `Scala` into a notebook environment;

- `Jupyter Scala (Almond)`
- `Spylon Kernel`
- `Apache Zeppelin`
- `Polynote`

In each of these `Scala` environments I've tried to connect to an existing cluster using the following script:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .master("spark:<ipaddress>:7077)
  .getOrCreate()
```

However when I go to the WebUI at `localhost:8080` I don't see anything running on the cluster.

I am able to connect to the cluster using `pyspark`, but need help with connecting `Scala` to the cluster.

Comment: How did you run `Jupyter Scala (Almond)`?

Comment: I ran it the same way as the others.